# User area and file sharing?

Tags: add-on

is there a way to enable users to upload files that only the user is able to see/download.

Admin needs to be able to manage the user's files and upload/delete these from the backend.

So a user registers an account -> can access user area with his files and upload/download -> admin can upload files for that user and manage user's files

Each user had his own area

Any addons that can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be achieved by [Smart Members Pro](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/smart-members-pro) and [Channel Images](https://eeharbor.com/channel-images) plugin. I am assuming that your website have `User section` from front-side and `Admin section` from beck-end to manage that `User section`.

Using **Smart Members Pro** :-

You should create `Member's Registration, Login, Update profile, Change password, Forgot password and reset password` by using this plugin. *For member area in EE this plugin is supreme.* So, that you can create separate member area for every registered User.

Using **Channel Images** :-

After making any **Channel** (having Channel Images field) to store images, You should make front-end form to upload the images by `logged_in` User by using `Channel form`. So, that user can upload the Images from front-end.

By this way **Member section** can be handled by `Smart Members Pro` and **Upload images** section can be handled by `Channel Images`. And to **assign Images to any member** you can create `Simple Text-box` and store respective **member-id** into it. Combination of these two plugin can achieve your requirement for sure.

Comment: Thanks I need to be able to upload and share any filetype from frontend and backend

Comment: For that you need *File* or *File Grid* fieldtype.